# Why I can't login in this website although I provided all the information that site needs python

Tags: python

So I created a code that logged me to a website, the website is 'filelist.io' and I used the requests method but it didn't work, the site uses a token to authorize the authentication, and 'validator' is the name of the token, my code provides all the authentication info but when I run the program I receive the login page instead of the home page of the website. Can someone help me with this?
This is the code that I use:

```
headers = {
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    'validator' : '',
    'username' : 'username',
    'password' : 'password',
    'returnto' : R'%2Fbrowse.php'
}
print(login_data)

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://filelist.io/browse.php'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    login_data['validator'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name' : 'validator'})['value']
    
    r = s.post(url, data = login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

Comment: What is the url when you see the login and when you are logged in? Is there any information about this login token on the internet?

Comment: No, I can't find information about that token, 'https://filelist.io/login.php?returnto=%2F' this is the link before login and after 'https://filelist.io/'

Comment: If there is no Api, then it is probably not intended to work like that... I guess the login is happening internaly

Comment: And I can use another method, or is just not possible to log in on this site?

Comment: I think this could help you: https://linuxhint.com/logging_into_websites_python/

Comment: I did the exact same thing, I guess my code is okay but the site just doesn't allow the login for some reason.

Comment: oh sorry, now i see it...
Then i have no idea, i am sorry

Comment: It's okay, thank you anyway!

Comment: I have possibly the solution, i'll write it as another answer

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute of form on `filelist.io` is set to `takelogin.php`. That means, that the POST request is sent to `filelist.io/takelogin.php` instead of  `filelist.io/browse.php`.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Answer (score 0):

As @Jon_Kle said you are sending the form to `https://filelist.io/browse.php`:

```py
url = 'https://filelist.io/browse.php'
...
r = s.post(url, data = login_data, headers=headers)
```

As you can see in the input form from `https://filelist.io/login.php`:

```html
<form method='post' action='takelogin.php'>
```

the form should be sent to `https://filelist.io/takelogin.php`:

```py
r = s.post('https://filelist.io/takelogin.php', data=login_data)
```

---

You could create a dictionary with all the forms input and pass it as `login_data` after changing the `username` and `password` keys:

```py
login_data = {form_input['name']: form_input.get('value','') for form_input in soup.select('input[name]')}         
login_data['username'] = 'your_username_here'
login_data['password'] = 'your_password_here'
```

instead of:

```py
login_data = {
    'validator' : '',
    'username' : 'username',
    'password' : 'password',
    'returnto' : R'%2Fbrowse.php'
}
...
login_data['validator'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name' : 'validator'})['value']
```

This automatically gets you the `validator` and `returnto` fields.

This could also be reused on other websites that require login as it's not hard coded.

---

You could then search with:

```py
search_string = "ubuntu linux"
search = s.get(f'https://filelist.io/browse.php?search={search_string.replace(" ", "+")}&cat=0&searchin=1&sort=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(search.text, 'html.parser')
```

And search for `class_='torrentrow'` giving you a list with torrents results:

```py
results = soup(class_='torrentrow')
```

The you can use a for loop to iterate through each result:

```py
for element in results:
    # title from 'a' tag
    print('Title = ', element.contents[1].a['title'])
    # 'id' by striping 'href' also from 'a' tag
    id = element.contents[1].a['href'].lstrip('details.php?id=')
    print(f"{id = }")
    # create download link now that you have the 'id'
    print(f'Download link = https://filelist.io/download.php?id={id}')
    # also create details link with 'id'
    print(f'Details link = https://filelist.io/details.php?id={id}')
    # acces 'seeders' and 'leechers'
    print(f'Seeders = {element.contents[8].text.strip()}')
    print(f'Leechers = {element.contents[9].text.strip()}')
```